# Unity Ads showing test ads

Tags: unity

I am implementing Unity Ads in my game and for some reason I have the test ads showing up in my production version of my app. I have the advertisements initialized with test ads turned off and I have even gone into my settings on the Unity Ads admin and set it to force test ads to be off. I'm not sure what else to do here.

Here is how I am initializing:

```
Advertisement.Initialize("myID", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have correctly entered your App Details on Unity Ads Dashboard after throwing it live on store.

Second, make sure you must not enabled test ads via Unity Ads Dashboard Settings.

Have a look,

[image: Unity Ads Dashboard App Settings]

Comment: Thank you but I have already done all of this. Test ads have been turned off just as you have shown with no luck. I am working with unity ads support now to see what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have not registered your device as a test device!

Comment: Thanks but I don't have any devices registered as a test device.